# a simple code, what is result of return?

Tags: java

I am a new programmer, I don't know what is the result of this return? I comment it. Is that true that there is {} follow by if()? Thank you

```
  public void blow(int amount)
  {
     if (this.popped)
         return;                                          //what is this? true or false
     this.radius += amount;
     if (this.radius <= this.maxRadius)
          return;                                         // what is this?
     this.radius = 0;
     this.popped = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first:  one does not return values from a method that is declared to return `void`.

These `return` statements are acting as early exits; they simply force the execution of the method to stop ([more formally, "completes abruptly"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17)) and return control to its caller without any result.  A side-effect will occur if it advances past the first `return`, as the state of `radius` will have been altered at that point.

More formally, this is coming from the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7) on why this is permissible:

> **If a method is declared `void`, then its body must not contain any return statement (§14.17) that has an Expression, or a compile-time error occurs.**

In general, it's not a good practice to have multiple exit paths, as it can make debugging a bit of a pain, and lead to confusion while reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

This just returns the control flow back to the place from where the function was called. It terminates the execution of blow.

Edit: Since your function has a return type of void, you cannot have a value returned, so any which way you look at this the return is just to terminate the function.

This is what it is

```
 public void blow(int amount)
 {
     if (this.popped)
         return;                     //This stops the function right here, no lines
                                     //in the function beyond this are executed
     this.radius += amount;

     if (this.radius <= this.maxRadius)
         return;                     // same as above

     this.radius = 0;
     this.popped = true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your method has a return type of void, which means it can't return anything. The `return;` statement just allows you to skip the rest of the code inside the method and exit the method.